# Copy constructor does not work and causes memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dynamic-arrays

For my own created Vector class:

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double* elem;
    int n;

public:
    Vector();
    Vector(const int s);
    Vector(Vector&);
    ~Vector();

    void print();

    void set(const int, const double);
    double get(const int) const;
    int size() const;
    double norm() const;
    Vector add(const Vector&) const;
    Vector subtract(const Vector&) const;
    double scalar(const Vector&) const;

};
```

When I try to call the copy constructor:

```
Vector::Vector(Vector& x)
{
int count = 0;
n = x.n;
elem = new double[n];
while (count < n)
    {
    elem[n] = x.elem[n];
    count++;
    }
}
```

It copies the address instead of the elements of the vector. Does anybody have an idea why this happen?

P.S. I In the destructor I have written

```
delete []elem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
Vector(Vector&);
```

it is not signature for a copy constructor. Right signature would be

```
Vector(const Vector&);
```

Compiler doesn't see user defined copy constructor and silently generates it's own default copy constructor which just make copy of

```
double* elem;
int n;
```

and doesn't care about allocation new memory and copying elements of array.

Answer (score -1):

```
Vector::Vector(Vector& x)
{
int count = 0;
n = x.n;
elem = new double[n];
while (count < n)
    {
    elem[n] = x.elem[n];//here should be:elem[count] = x.elem[count]
    count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing half of the problem. The memory leak.

Comment: It might help to explain what you've actually changed... Otherwise it's a game of "spot the difference" against the original code